# Find first element in array that matches a specific condition in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Let's say I have an array like so:

```
[
    ["required": true],
    ["required": true],
    ["required": false],
    ["required": false],
    ["required": false],
    ["required": false],
    ["required": false]
]
```

I want to insert a new element into this array at the index where `required` first equals `false` (at position 2). I'm sure I could determine this using a basic for-each loop, e.g.:

```
var idx = 0
for (i, el) in myArray.enumerate() {
    if el["required"] == false {
        idx = i
        break
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem very Swift-like. Is there a cleaner (i.e. less code) way of doing this in Swift 2? Perhaps something using filter or map?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
let idx = myArray.indexOf({$0["required"] == false})
```

---

Swift 3:

```
let idx = myArray.index(where: { $0["required"] == false })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let required    = array.filter { $0["required"] == true }
let notRequired = array.filter { $0["required"] == false }
let result      = required + [["required": true]] + notRequired
```